# Database Modeling for Application with Many Integrations

Tags: database-design, relational-database, nosql

I’m working on an application that requires many 3rd-party integrations. I’m using Postgres to store these API responses but am having trouble for a number of reasons.

1. These objects are frequently large and require me to model the relationships to fields.
2. Many 3rd party responses have some sort of inherited relationship with models I have created.

As such, the database is getting increasingly complex.

The true source of my frustration here is it feels like I’m doing the work twice; once in Go where I write out these models to be unmarshaled and again in SQL to create and model the appropriate tables.

My question: is this a good use case for a NoSQL database? I usually avoid NoSQL because I don’t like the feeling of arbitrary data being stored. However, I’m thinking that I’m already setting the constraints in Go so it should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with an integration of things, is that usually the parts have to be specifically designed to integrate. If not, there can be excess complexity in the result, or even the parts can be found irreconcilable (incompatible with being integrated).

Usually, with "3rd party" parts and APIs, you cannot expect to change them to make them fit into a bespoke integration of your own, so it's just coincidence if any two can be integrated.

Technological differences that require translation processes, and require repetitive source code to be written and kept aligned, are an example of the development complexity that can ensue from many kinds of integration.

It's not clear from your post what the "model" is what you are designing. It's not clear what APIs, technologies, and data formats are being used.

And it's not clear what you intend to do with the data in Postgres. It's not clear whether there is dependency on the facilities of the SQL language or an SQL database engine, or whether this is just being used lightly and something else could easily be substituted.

Mainstream client-server SQL engines, like Postgres, are designed around a central purpose of handling OLTP loads, which are characterised by high levels of concurrency and the need for high levels of availability and reliability.

The SQL language itself is designed around the central purpose of processing and storage of finely-grained structured data in bulk, and nowadays there are very few manipulations of data to which it is not suited.

You'd have to use your knowledge of your particular integration to decide whether it requires an SQL engine or not.